# Change GPIO pin for DS18B20+ One Wire Digital Temperature Sensor

Tags: gpio, touchscreen, ds18b20

First question on this SE site so please be gentle.

Trying to get the above mentioned temp sensor working on the RPi but with a touch screen installed.   When I run the following steps nothing starting with 28 appears.

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices
ls
cd 28-xxxx (change this to match what serial number pops up)
cat w1_slave
```

I'm guessing this is because I have it plugged into pin 16.  I have read that the single wire sensors I/O only works on pin 4 but you can change it as described [on the RPI forum.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=65137).

I tried this and when I run the instructions as per [Adafruits](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing?view=all) nothing shows up.  [This is the temp sensor](https://amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00IZTVHJQ?ref_=pe_931411_45466481) and [this is the screen](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00OFLKPG4?psc=1).

Any help would be very much received.  This 'simple' project is turning out to be more difficult that I imagined.  Thinking, I should have done it on a Arduino now :(

Regards

Chris

Comment: Sorry, not allowed to put these links above so here they are[3]: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00IZTVHJQ?ref_=pe_931411_45466481
  [4]: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00OFLKPG4?psc=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be manually loading the w1-gpio and w1-therm modules.

You should now be using the device tree method of configuration.

Add the following to /boot/config.txt and reboot.

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=x
```

where x is the (Broadcom) GPIO number you want to use for the 1-wire bus.

For a description of the GPIOs and the numbering scheme see this [Gadgetoid](http://pinout.xyz/) page.

Comment: Hi Joan,  Thanks for this.  It now appears to have loaded although I still needed to type the modprobe lines.  Now I have three files including  00-80000000(lots) but I cannot see where I now read the temperature from because the adafruits tells me that w1_slave should provide a value?   Can you help?  Thanks

Comment: Are you using Raspbian?  Adafruit used to distribute an image called Occidentalis which should be avoided.

Comment: Yes.   I have noticed that these numbers/serials keep changing.

Comment: Ignore me.  I just found a better reference for the Broadcom Pin numbers vs other representations at http://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin36_gpio16.   It seems to make more sense now.  Could you edit your original answer to include the link I have provided so its clear to people how to find correct Broadcom Pin.    Otherwise, huge thanks.  Now for the python bit.

Comment: The numbers should not change.  That would suggest a poor, or loose, or incorrect connection.  My /sys/bus/w1/devices/ shows two DS18B20 directories, 28-000005d34cd2, and  28-001414abbeff.  Each has a w1_slave file.  When I cat the file I get a temperature reading (among other information).  You SHOULD NOT have needed to do the modprobe if device tree is properly enabled.  What does uname -a report?

Comment: Hi Joan,  Yes its all working now as per my comment above.  Just needed the right reference for pin numbers.   Got the temperature showing on a Python TK Window and updating.   Please see comment re link.   Thanks again for the help.